# Sources 'Compile' But Do Not Appear In Out Directory

Tags: java, scala

My project was compiling fine.  All of the sudden I start receiving `ClassNotFoundException` for files which have no errors.

I realized that in the 'out' directory, where compiled sources are supposed to go, is empty.

IDE says compilation went fine: 0 Errors, 0 Warnings.

This is affecting both scala and java files.

It was definitely working, and for some reason just stopped working.

Have any idea why this is happening?

Using IntelliJ 14. 
Barebones Play 2.0 project. Scala 2.11.4. JDK 1.8.

Can provide logs if you can point where to look.

*** UPDATE: Barebones Play and Scala Project ***

To isolate the issue I create a brand-new Play 2.0 project and a blank Scala project.  I added a Test object to each and ran.  The Scala only project worked fine, the Play 2.0 gave the same error I have been having.

I think this clearly points to Play 2.0 as the culprit.

Comment: Definitely more information about you project setup/build tool is required. However as a first step of investigation I'd suggest trying a fresh build after calling `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: @NorbertRadyk Did that and more many times to no avail.  Adding some info now.

Comment: Have you tried compiling/running it from SBT rather than IntelliJ directly?

Comment: @NorbertRadyk I can try that as a temporary workaround.  But why did the IntelliJ run work before?

Comment: Please do try to compile with SBT and report back any errors if they appeared, or that it succeeded.

Comment: @Zoltán I tried to compile with SBT, no errors reported.  Still no files in the out directory and of course ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference here is that for Play, SBT is handling the compilation and the test module must be added to SBT.

While for the plain Scala project, IntelliJ is handling the compilation and doesn't need a standard src directory configuration by default as SBT does.